# What is the best way to define admin section and front end section in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Please let me know about how can separated admin and frond end section. and what is the best way:

1. By using Plugin.
2. By using admin_ prefix.

Or another option.

Comment: 3. Plugin with admin_ prefixed actions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can build your admin section in a plugin as said above:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins

and then create your admin routing to go to that plugin:

```
Router::connect(
'/admin',
array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

Described here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing